# MSChart X-axis always starting at -1?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have an MSChart control on my windows form and each time I run this with my data, the X-axis always shows -1,0,1,2,etc

My data nor its index should have caused this, its as though its a setting somewhere in the charts properties. Could anyone please tell me which setting could cause this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
YourChartArea.AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few days ago with a simple bar chart that reported the number of work orders closed for the past 7 days.  The X-Axis was always starting at 0 and ending at 8 no matter what settings I chose.  I finally discovered a way to get the X-Axis to only show 1 through 7 which is what I desired.  My solution is below:

1) Open the ChartArea collection
2) Click on the applicable ChartArea
3) Click on the Axes collection
4) Click on the X axis member
5) If your X axis properties are categorized, browse to your LabelStyle properties
6) Change isEndLabelVisible to false

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own minimum:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
```